# How to make resizable textarea with editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to make textarea resizable with editor, as its height should be increased according to content, I managed to make textarea resizable but after after applying editor it's not working.

I am using tinymce.js for editor

thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

After you replace the `<textarea>` with TinyMCE, you'll need to configure the TinyMCE instance. Initialise TinyMCE with the following setting:

```
theme_advanced_resizing: true
```

If you don't want horizontal resizing:

```
theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false
```